# How to Delete all the event from My calendar in my device Android

Tags: android, calendar

I found a lot of question or tutorial about that but no one could work for me.

So i will appreciate if someone can give me a complete solution on How to Delete all my event from my calendar

Thanks for Helping!!!!

Comment: refer: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/insert-delete-events-in-android-calendar-t48488.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no calendar in the Android OS.

If you are referring to your Google Calendar, use the Google Calendar GData APIs.

Answer (score 0):

try this it ll help u

if ur device is less than 2.1 mean u use below uri

```
uri="content://calendar/events"
```

greeater than 2.1 mean

```
uri="content://com.android.calendar/events" 

Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(uri),    null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

// fetching calendars id
if(cursor.getcount>0)
{
CId = new int[cursor.getCount()];
int i=0;  
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
CId[i] = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
i++;
cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

delete a calender event

```
for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++)
{
Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse(uri);
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI,Cid[i]);
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way:

```
Uri eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");  // or "content://com.android.calendar/events" 


Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(eventUri, new String[]{"_id"}, "calendar_id = " + calendarId, null, null); // calendar_id can change in new versions 

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventUri, cursor.getInt(0));

    contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
}
```